# I don't know why the double values are displayed in postman. Is the my code correct?

Tags: spring-boot, postman, spring-boot-jpa

This is my Book class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="book")
public class Book {

@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
@ManyToOne(targetEntity=Category.class,cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="CategoryId")
public Category category;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(length=10)
private int book_id;
@Column(length=128)
private String title;
@Column(length=64)
private String author;
@Column(length=200)
private String description;
@Column(length=10)
private int ISBN;
@Column(length=10)
private float price;
private Date published_Date;
@Lob
@Column
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private byte[] icon;
//getter and setter
}
```

This is my Category class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="category1")
public class Category {
@Id   
@Column(length=12)   
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
public int CategoryId;
@Column(length=50)
public String CategoryName;

//@JsonBackReference
@OneToMany(mappedBy="category")
private List<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();
//getter and setter
}
```

The relationship between them is one to many.
This is my Category Service class

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class AdminServiceImpl implements AdminService {
@Autowired
private CategoryDao dao;

@Autowired
private BookDao dao1;

@Override
public List<Category> getAllCategory(){
    return dao.findAll();
}
}
```

My Controller class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/bookstore")
public class CategoryController {
@Autowired
private AdminService service;

@GetMapping("/GetAllCategory")
private ResponseEntity<List<Category>> getAllCategory() {
    List<Category> catlist = service.getAllCategory();
    return new ResponseEntity<List<Category>>(catlist, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.OK);

}
}
```

My category table already has data.When i try to display them it is showing double values.
[Displaying values using Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YR4f.png)
The Category table in the Database: [Database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVlI2.png)

Answer (score 0):

Jackson's ObjectMapper uses the Java bean pattern and it expects the following

```
public class Foo {
    public Object bar;

    public Object getBar() {...}

    public void setBar(Object bar) {...}
}
```

The getters and setters start with get and set, respectively, followed by the corresponding field name with its first letter capitalized.

Change

`CategoryId` to `categoryId`  (first letter lowercase)

and

`CategoryName` to `categoryName`